# java: generic exception does not catch java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: java, http, exception

I have the following code. It's called repeatedly to crawl the web

```
    public GetWebPageResult(String htmlCode) //CONSTRUCTORS FOR GetWebPageResults
{
    if(htmlCode!=null)
    {
        this.htmlCode=htmlCode;
        htmlErrorCode=-1;
        excCode=0;

    }
    else
    {
        this.htmlCode=null;
        htmlErrorCode=-1;
        excCode=UNKNOWN_ERROR;
    }
}

public GetWebPageResult(int excCode, int htmlErrorCode)
{
    this.htmlCode=null;
    this.excCode=excCode;
    this.htmlErrorCode=htmlErrorCode;
} //END CONSTRUCTORS FOR GetWebPageResults


    static private GetWebPageResult getWebPage(PageNode pagenode)
{
    String result;
    String inputLine;
    URI url;
    int cicliLettura=0;
    long startTime=0, endTime, openConnTime=0,connTime=0, readTime=0;
    try
    {
        startTime=System.nanoTime();
        result="";
        url=pagenode.getUri();      //fare qualcosa se getURI è null
        if(Core.logGetWebPage())
            openConnTime=System.nanoTime();
        if(url!=null)
        {
            HttpURLConnection yc = (HttpURLConnection) url.toURL().openConnection(); //controllare yc
            if(url.toURL().getProtocol().equalsIgnoreCase("https"))
                yc=(HttpsURLConnection)yc;
            yc.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-GB;     rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"); 
            yc.connect();           //controllare il risultato di .connect => non c'è! al max lancia IOEXC
            if(checkResponseCode(yc.getResponseCode())==false)
                return new GetWebPageResult(GetWebPageResult.ERR_BAD_RESPONSE_CODE,yc.getResponseCode());
            if(Core.logGetWebPage())
                connTime=System.nanoTime();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));//può lanciare IOEXC
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                buffer.append(inputLine).append('\n');
                cicliLettura++;
            }
            result = buffer.toString();

            if(Core.logGetWebPage())
                readTime=System.nanoTime();
            in.close();
            yc.disconnect();
            if(Core.logGetWebPage())
            {
                endTime=System.nanoTime();
                        //url.toURL() non è null, controllato prima
                System.out.println(/*result+*/"getWebPage eseguito in "+(endTime-startTime)/1000000+" ms. Size: "+result.length()+" Response Code="+yc.getResponseCode()+" Protocollo="+url.toURL().getProtocol()+" openConnTime: "+(openConnTime-startTime)/1000000+" connTime:"+(connTime-openConnTime)/1000000+" readTime:"+(readTime-connTime)/1000000+" cicliLettura="+cicliLettura+" pagina:"+url.toURL());
            }
            return new GetWebPageResult(result);
        }
        else
            return new GetWebPageResult(GetWebPageResult.ERR_NULL_URI,-2);
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Eccezione1: "+e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();  
        return new GetWebPageResult(GetWebPageResult.ERR_HTML_IOEXCEPTION,-2);
    }catch(ClassCastException e){
        System.out.println("Eccezione2: "+e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace(); 
        return new GetWebPageResult(GetWebPageResult.ERR_CLASS_CAST_EXC,-2);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Eccezione ERR_NOT_LISTED_EXC: "+e.toString());
        return new GetWebPageResult(GetWebPageResult.ERR_NOT_LISTED_EXC,-2);
    }
}
```

The thread stopped with this exception:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: www.notjohnchow.com
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at WebsiteCrawler.getWebPage(WebsiteCrawler.java:315)
at WebsiteCrawler.crawlNextPage(WebsiteCrawler.java:71)
at Website.run(Website.java:51)
```

The exception is launched by yc.connect, when trying to connect to "www.notjohnchow.com"
Why isn't the last catch block getting the exception? I've set the try-catch to catch many exceptions and, if the current exception is not one of the first, i thread it like an "unknown error" in the catch(Exception e) block.

Comment: It is rather strange, since it is a checked exception.  Are you completely sure that the code you pasted is exactly what you are executing and then producing the error?

Comment: Of Course. I have just done CTRL+Z, nothing was modified. i've started the application this morning, i have just noticed about this exception.. I'm logging on a file, and the exception output has been wrote on the Eclipse console

Comment: Nice one, @BackSlash, but the stack trace does not bring us there :(

Comment: @mark Could you try to redeploy your application with some trivial code change (a carry return somewhere or something like that) in order to make it reload that particular binary?  It looks like it could be executing some version prior to your adding of the final catch block

Comment: @BackSlash of course, just done. Why people have set -2 for this question? :S

Comment: Interesting. @Jorge_B It's really weird, I can reproduce that error: http://ideone.com/ImxFzH

Comment: Omg, maybe @Vampire is right. The last catch(Exception e) was added days ago..  I have updated the exception, there are some more rows over there. The strange thing (at least, for me) is that i have redirected all the console output on a file, but that exception was reported on the console. Maybe i got some panic. Why is it reporting a non-fatal exception on the console? - Cannot edit; at last i see a NullPointerException (fatal)

Comment: @BackSlash: uhm? do you mean it is a bug?

Comment: @mark I really don't know... It should be catched by the `IOException` catch block, and it shouldn't print the stacktrace to `stderr`, but it does, maybe I'm missing something

Comment: Interesting... please vote up the question? Maybe someone else will join... really don't know why people hate this question

Comment: @mark why should it not print the stacktrace? You do it yourself. e.printStackTrace() does the printing, so this is expected. If you just redirect stdout to file, this is correct behavior. As my answer was correct, please accept it as answer. :-)

Comment: @Vampire should't it start with "Eccezione.." then stacktrace?

Comment: @mark No. You said you redirect stdout to a file, so that message will be in the file. Exception.printStackTrace() writes to stderr though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure your thread died? If I'm not completely wrong from the top of my head, UnknownHostException is a descendent of IOException and this caught by your first catch block and thus the StackTrace printed.

Comment: You're absolutely correct.  The try/catch *DID* catch the exception ... which happens to be a subclass of IOException: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/UnknownHostException.html